# Error when building nginx docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I am trying to build a docker from a fork and I am getting the following error when performing `docker build  ./`:

```
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.o] Error 1
objs/Makefile:748: recipe for target 'objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.o' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/nginx/nginx-1.8.0'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

On install we run

```
apt-get -y install libpcre3-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl build-essential wget
```

I can't find this error on google. The full error for reference as I can't find out the exact error reference I need to research:

```
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c: In function 'ngx_ssl_init':
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:112:5: error: 'OPENSSL_config' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
     OPENSSL_config(NULL);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ct.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:61,
                 from src/event/ngx_event_openssl.h:15,
                 from src/core/ngx_core.h:80,
                 from src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:9:
/usr/include/openssl/conf.h:92:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(void OPENSSL_config(const char *config_name))
 ^
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c: In function 'ngx_ssl_rsa512_key_callback':
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:753:9: error: 'RSA_generate_key' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
         key = RSA_generate_key(512, RSA_F4, NULL, NULL);
         ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/rsa.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:50,
                 from src/event/ngx_event_openssl.h:15,
                 from src/core/ngx_core.h:80,
                 from src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:9:
/usr/include/openssl/rsa.h:193:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_0_9_8(RSA *RSA_generate_key(int bits, unsigned long e, void
 ^
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c: In function 'ngx_ssl_dhparam':
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:943:11: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'DH {aka struct dh_st}'
         dh->p = BN_bin2bn(dh1024_p, sizeof(dh1024_p), NULL);
           ^~
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c: In function 'ngx_ssl_handshake':
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:1164:31: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'SSL {aka struct ssl_st}'
         if (c->ssl->connection->s3) {
                               ^~
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c: In function 'ngx_ssl_connection_error':
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:1913:21: error: 'SSL_R_NO_CIPHERS_PASSED' undeclared (first use in this function)
             || n == SSL_R_NO_CIPHERS_PASSED                          /*  182 */
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:1913:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c: In function 'ngx_ssl_session_cache':
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:2107:43: error: passing argument 2 of 'SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
         SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb(ssl->ctx, ngx_ssl_get_cached_session);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src/event/ngx_event_openssl.h:15:0,
                 from src/core/ngx_core.h:80,
                 from src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:9:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:637:6: note: expected 'SSL_SESSION * (*)(struct ssl_st *, const unsigned char *, int,  int *) {aka struct ssl_session_st * (*)(struct ssl_st *, const unsigned char *, int,  int *)}' but argument is of type 'SSL_SESSION * (*)(SSL *, u_char *, int,  int *) {aka struct ssl_session_st * (*)(struct ssl_st *, unsigned char *, int,  int *)}'
 void SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb(SSL_CTX *ctx,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c: In function 'ngx_ssl_session_id_context':
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:2129:27: error: storage size of 'md' isn't known
     EVP_MD_CTX            md;
                           ^~
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:2195:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&md);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c: In function 'ngx_ssl_session_ticket_key_callback':
src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:2864:9: error: 'RAND_pseudo_bytes' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
         RAND_pseudo_bytes(iv, 16);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/engine.h:19:0,
                 from src/event/ngx_event_openssl.h:22,
                 from src/core/ngx_core.h:80,
                 from src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:9:
/usr/include/openssl/rand.h:47:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(int RAND_pseudo_bytes(unsigned char *buf, int num))
 ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.o] Error 1
objs/Makefile:748: recipe for target 'objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.o' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/nginx/nginx-1.8.0'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

This is the docker fork I am running https://github.com/meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting various errors and warnings here, but they aren't really about Docker or OpenSSL. If we strip away the extraneous information, here are the problems you are encountering.

```
error: 'OPENSSL_config' is deprecated
error: 'RSA_generate_key' is deprecated
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'DH {aka struct dh_st}'
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'SSL {aka struct ssl_st}'
error: 'SSL_R_NO_CIPHERS_PASSED' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: passing argument 2 of 'SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb' from incompatible pointer type
error: storage size of 'md' isn't known
error: implicit declaration of function 'EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup'
error: 'RAND_pseudo_bytes' is deprecated
```

The core of the problem here is probably that you are using a legacy version of Nginx in this project. From the GitHub repository you pointed to, in `install-nginx.sh`:

```
NGINX_VERSION=1.8.0
```

The current mainline version of Nginx is 1.13.2. I haven't combed through the changelogs for Nginx, but based on the errors you are receiving, it seems likely that between the 1.8 releases and the current ones, OpenSSL has deprecated various functions that Nginx 1.8 relied on. Most likely this can be solved by moving to a recent release of Nginx.

As of this writing, 1.13.2 is the current mainline, and 1.12.0 is the current stable. One of those may work better. Whether you can simply drop this in, I can't say. You may have to change something in the build scripts or the nginx config for a more recent version to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Dan. Will look into this.

Comment: Changing the nginx to version 1.12.0 worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

you are getting this error because your nginx version don't support SSL 1.1.0.  Either upgrade NGINX version or use SSL 1.0.2.